# Set access control in Symfony2 for URL with querystring

Tags: symfony, query-string, access-control, symfony-2.6

I want to allow access to users with ROLE_ADMIN to the following path:

```
/admin
```

And only allow access to users with ROLE_CONTENT or ROLE_ADMIN to the following path:

```
/admin?select=pending
```

Here is my access control config in `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin?select=pending, role: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CONTENT ] }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

However if I try to access to the query string path with a user with `ROLE_CONTENT` it gives me a `403` access denied error message.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: First of all, links like /admin?select=pending are soooo not "symfony-y". So i suggest to make 2 actions (one for /admin/, and one for /admin/{select}/), and define the roles for those 2 actions / routes. Also do you need the select thingy to be below the /admin/ route? looking at your roles, it would be logical to take that out of there, so the content in /admin/ would stay there, and that other select-something content would go to something like /anotheradminroute/{select}/. You can than tell symfony what the {select} variable can be (in your case 'pending'). Check documentation on routing.

Comment: I understand what you mean and at first I tried it that way. However the querystring represents a `select` inside a form, so when the submit button is clicked, it sends the get parameter and updates the list of results. I didn't find an easy way to change the form action when the select option is changed in order to send to a different path instead of `/admin`. I could do it easyly with JS, but doing it that way, I am not able to use the `path` function in order for it to work in local, devel and production environments.

Comment: Mhm that's understandable. I think you should check the $request method in the beginnig of your adminAction (or whatever action is at /admin route). If the method is POST, you can make a redirect to /admin/{select}/ by reading out the $select variable from your form. Sounds good?